# How to increase throughput of a Scrapy cluster targetting one website?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, cluster-computing

I am using 4 Ubuntu Host in Linode to crawl ~10k url per hour, using a Scrapy cluster configuration. How to increase the speed of getting request from queue ASAP?

I am using the same domain for all the URL.

Comment: Out of a sample of 10K URLs, how many will be for the same domain/site? If you are scraping from a large number of URLs from a small number of sites, then you need to slow your scraping down, not speed it up.

Comment: Thanks, I am Using single domain for all url.

Comment: Right, you are targetting a single website. The faster you make this, the more like a denial of service attack you will make it, until such point that the owner blocks your IP range. I'd recommend a minimum of 1-2 seconds delay between each request, otherwise you will be unfairly passing your operating costs to a third party who cannot easily reject them.